# How can I handle the exception in Django 1.8.7

Tags: python, django

When I run the development server in Django, exception occurs as follows.

> ?: (1_7.W001) MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is not set.
>       HINT: Django 1.7 changed the global defaults for the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware, django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware, and django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware were removed from the defaults. If your project needs these middleware then you should configure this setting.

Here is my settings.py file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

On the browser, there is an error message as follows.

> ImproperlyConfigured at /
>     app_dirs must not be set when loaders is defined.
>     Request Method:   GET
>     Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/
>     Django Version:   1.8.7
>     Exception Type:   ImproperlyConfigured
>     Exception Value:
>     app_dirs must not be set when loaders is defined.
>     Exception Location:   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/engine.py in **init**, line 36

Would you tell me the reason why this exception has occurred and how can I handle it?

Comment: I would like to render base.html file I have created in **templates** directory, but I can't because of the exception described above.

Comment: You set `MIDDLEWARE` which was introduced in Django 1.10, but you need `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in Django 1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

add this and remove the other middleware

add this in place of apps_dirs

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR + '/templates/',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
            'debug': True
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough. The exception on the terminal has disappeared. Would you tell me the difference between MIDDLEWARE and MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. As a matter of fact, when I install Django, there is MIDDLEWARE in settings.py.

Comment: haha, dont be bro, we all dont  know everything, we make mistakes and learn, anyways dont forget to upvote the ans

Comment: The exception on the browser doesn't disappear. What can I do for it?

Comment: show your full settings file. and view if you have created any

Comment: Hi. As you can see on my badge, I'm new to stackowerflow. I wanna show you full settings.py file, but I don't know the way. How can I?

Answer (score 0):

When I remove **'APP_DIRS' : True**, the exception on the browser has disappeared.